# How to Reshow ngbAlert (Bootstrap widgest for Angular) message again after dismissing it

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using [ngbAlert](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/api) for Angular. I am showing a alert if my backend API fails.

```
<ngb-alert class="veri-alert" [type]="alert.type" [dismissible]="true" *ngIf="showErrorAlert">
<span class="icon icon-alert-dark"></span>
<span class="pl-2">{{ alert.message }}</span>
</ngb-alert>
```

[image]

If the API fails I am making `showErrorAlert` true and the alert is shown as expected. Now if the user clicks on the 'x' button in alert-box, the alert closes as expected.
Now, If the user again makes an API call to backend by clicking continue button without refreshing and again the API fails, I do make `showErrorAlert` as true again. But now, the ngbAlert is not shown.

How can I make the ngbAlert to show again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a working example, where the closing of the alert works fine. I added the event `(closed)="showErrorAlert = false"` to the HTML and it started working fine!

html

```
<ngb-alert
  class="veri-alert"
  [type]="alert.type"
  [dismissible]="true"
  *ngIf="showErrorAlert"
  #staticAlert
  (closed)="showErrorAlert = false"
>
  <span class="icon icon-alert-dark"></span>
  <span class="pl-2">{{ alert.message }}</span>
</ngb-alert>

<button (click)="clickAction()">open alert</button>
```

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbAlertModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-alert-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgbAlertModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './alert-basic.html',
})
export class NgbdAlertBasic {
  showErrorAlert = false;
  alert = {
    type: 'success',
    message: 'it is working!',
  };

  clickAction() {
    this.showErrorAlert = true;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgv53e?file=src%2Fapp%2Falert-basic.html,src%2Fapp%2Falert-basic.ts)